# Is there any way to create xml file in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I am using adobe flash builder 4.6

it does not support "File" keywords.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an XML file in the Flash Builder IDE, or you want to load a file in a running Flex App? If the app is deployed on the web, you will only have access to web accessible files (EG. through a public URL). File system access is restricted (for good reason) to Desktop and Mobile AIR deployments.

Comment: To create xml file in flash builder ide

Comment: You can just select new file and save it a .xml extension, but I added some additional info in my answer about the eclipse (Flash Builder) XML tools

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project type.  To get access to the File class, you need to be working in an AIR project:

[image: Screenshot of the New Flex Project wizard]

As drkstr1 pointed out, A Flex project for Web can't save files in this way for very good security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder, select new -> Other, then select the XML file type.

[image]

If you don't have this option, go to Help -> Install New Software

[image]